# Session management in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working on a login screen where i have to enter email id and password.On successful login ,i want to store email ID in Shared Preference so that next time when i want to login ,i don't have to enter the email Id.I am using a SessionManager class to perform this.

**1.SessionMAnager.java**

```
public class SessionManager {
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context context;
//Shared Preferences file name
private static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "SessionManager";
// Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";
//Email Address
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

//Constructor
public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

//Create Login session
public void createUserLoginSession(String email) {

    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);
    //Storing email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    //editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN,true);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Check login method will check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else do anything
 */

public boolean checkLogin() {
    // Check login status
    if (!this.isUserLoggedIn()) {

        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Activity_LogInScreen.class);

        // Staring Login Activity
        context.startActivity(i);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Get stored session data
 */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {

    //Use hashmap to store user credentials
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // user email id
    user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Clear session details
 */
public void logoutUser() {

    // Clearing all user data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Activity_LogInScreen.class);

    // Staring Login Activity
    context.startActivity(i);
}

// Check for login
public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, false);
}
```

}

**2.Activity_LoginScreen.java**

```
public class Activity_LogInScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText editText;
private EditText editTextpassword;

private Button btn_SignUp;
private Button btn_LogIn;

public String get_User, get_Password;
private CheckConnectionInternet obj;
private TransparentProgressDialog dialog;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
JSONObject jsonObj;
public Model_LoginDetails objLoginDetails;
private ArrayList<Model_LoginDetails> arr_LogInUserDetails = new ArrayList<Model_LoginDetails>();
AlmabayDatabase almabayDatabase;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
//SessionManager class
SessionManager sessionManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginscreen);

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
    dialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(Activity_LogInScreen.this, R.drawable.loader);
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(Prefs_Registration.pacakgename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    obj = new CheckConnectionInternet();
    almabayDatabase = new AlmabayDatabase(this);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_useremailId);
    editTextpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_userpassword);
    editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    editTextpassword.getBackground().setColorFilter(
            Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    // Checking whether database contains the emailID or not
   /* if (almabayDatabase.getEmailFromAccessTAble() != null) {
        get_User = almabayDatabase.getEmailFromAccessTAble();
        editText.setText(get_User);
    }*/
Boolean userLoogein = sessionManager.isUserLoggedIn();
    Log.e("IslOOgedIn", String.valueOf(userLoogein));

    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
    // get email
    String email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    Log.e("email",email);


    btn_SignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_SignUp);
    btn_LogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    btn_SignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_LogIn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_login:
            get_User = editText.getText().toString();
            get_Password = editTextpassword.getText().toString();

            if ((get_User.equals("")) || (get_Password.equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(Activity_LogInScreen.this, "Fill Empty Field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (obj.isOnline(Activity_LogInScreen.this) == true) {
                    JARLogIn jar_Login = new JARLogIn(Activity_LogInScreen.this) {

                        private String status_Login;

                        @Override
                        public void result(String object) {
                            Log.e("Respose", object);
                            dialog.show();
                            try {
                                jsonObj = new JSONObject(object);
                                status_Login = jsonObj.getString("statusCode");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
 if (status_Login.equals("200")) {

                                String user_Id;
                                String access_token;
                                try {
                                    JSONObject detailsObject = jsonObj.getJSONObject("detail");
                                    String get_Id = detailsObject.getString("id");
                                    String get_AccsToken = detailsObject.getString("access_token");
                                    String userId = detailsObject.getString("user_id");
                                    JSONObject jsonUserInfo = detailsObject.getJSONObject("userInfo");
                                    JSONObject jsonuser = jsonUserInfo.getJSONObject("userInfo");

                                    //user
                                    JSONObject Json_user = jsonuser.getJSONObject("user");

                                    String str_thumbnail_url = Json_user.getString("thumbnail_url");
                                    String str_Name = Json_user.getString("name");
                                    String str_userSkills = Json_user.getString("userSkills");

                                    //create user's login session
                                    sessionManager.createUserLoginSession(get_User);

                                    // Delete the existing entries of AccessToken table
                                    almabayDatabase.deleteAllFromAccessTable();

                                    // Inserting UserID,emailID and access token in the database
                                    almabayDatabase.insertIntoAccessTable(Integer.parseInt(get_Id), get_User, get_AccsToken);

                                    objLoginDetails = new Model_LoginDetails(detailsObject.getString("id"), detailsObject.getString("user_id"), detailsObject.getString("access_token"), str_thumbnail_url, str_Name, str_userSkills);
                                    arr_LogInUserDetails.add(objLoginDetails);

                                    save_ValueSession(userId, get_AccsToken, get_User, str_Name, arr_LogInUserDetails, str_thumbnail_url);
                                    fun_empty_EditTextFields();
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            } else {

                                fun_empty_EditTextFields();
                                Toast.makeText(Activity_LogInScreen.this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }
 private void fun_empty_EditTextFields() {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            editText.setText("");
                            editTextpassword.setText("");
                        }
                    };
                    jar_Login.execute(get_User, get_Password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Activity_LogInScreen.this,
                            "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            break;

        case R.id.btn_SignUp:
            fun_Intent(Activity_Registeration.class);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In Activity_LoginScreen,i am storing the emailID in the shared preference using session manager class

```
//create user's login session
                                    sessionManager.createUserLoginSession(get_User);
```

Here i am getting NullPointerException.I know i am accessing the shared preference before putting values to it.But if i am using the database it is working for me.Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: Please provide Stacktrace which can be better for understanding?

Answer (score -1):

The problem which is occuring in your case might be the one where `JSONObject` might be working over something which is null.
More could be said if you mention your stacktrace.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17216016)

Comment: Well, thanks for stopping my reputation then, by downvoting it. So that those who might know the concepts but might not having the reputation enough, will end up doing nothing but just lookUp. A nice way to widespread a community, but still stupid

Comment: By the way: I'm not the down-voter. I hope soon you'll have enough reputation for commenting.